# Property of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

It is well known that if $X, Y$ are independent random variables with $XY$ integrable, then $X$ and $Y$ are integrable and:

$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$

Suppose that $\mathcal{G}$ is some sub-sigma-algebra of the probability space and that $X$ and $Y$ remain independent random variables. Is it true that (under suitable integrability conditions)

$\mathbb{E}(XY \, | \,\mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(X \, | \, \mathcal{G})\mathbb{E}(Y \, | \, \mathcal{G})$?

Thanks.

Comment: Define "X and Y remain independent random variables".

Comment: For clarity - I assume $X,Y$ real valued, using Borel sigma algebra on the reals. By 'X and Y remain independent' I just mean that I'm assuming (as in the non-conditional version of the result) that X and Y are independent random variables ($\mathbb{P}(X \in A, Y \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)\mathbb{P}(Y \in B)$ for all Borel measurable A and B.

Comment: Given that the RHS is clearly $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, it's enough to show if $Z$ is bounded and $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, then $\mathbb{E}(Z XY) = \mathbb{E}(Z E(X | \mathcal{G} ) E(Y | \mathcal{G} )$. By conditional expectation properties, the RHS = $\mathbb{E}(YZ E(X | \mathcal{G} )$ but I just can't seem to get rid of the final conditioning...I haven't used the independence of X and Y though - it's not clear how this helps. I suspect the result I asked about isn't true, though I'd be interested to see a counterexample.

Comment: Then write "X and Y are independent random variables". See answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The usual counterexample works:

> Consider $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed on $\{-1,1\}^2$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma(XY)$.

Then $(X,Y)$ is independent and $E[XY\mid\mathcal G]=XY$ since $XY$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, while $E[X\mid\mathcal G]=E[X]=0$ since $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ (likewise, $E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=E[Y]=0$). Hence $E[XY\mid\mathcal G]\ne E[X\mid\mathcal G]\cdot E[Y\mid\mathcal G]$.